# How to safely 'unget' a character with C's FILE* descriptor

Tags: c, input

Suppose you need to read a sequence of characters that will form a decimal integer in C, but you can't use `fscanf()`. The program will be tested with the following octets:

```
0x31 0x35 0x30 0x0a
```

or simply:

```
150\n
```

How do you make sure that only the first three bytes are extracted? In other words, a future call to `fgetc()` MUST return `0x0a`. This would be the exact same behavior of using `fscanf("%d")` and then `fgetc()`.

Comment: Why would you assume they wouldn't actually?

Comment: In C++ you can [peek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) at the next character in the buffer. You could also [unget the last character read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget), or even [put back any other character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, if you `scanf("%d",&x)` and `c = getchar()` the input `150\n`, `x` will hold 150 and `c` will hold `0x0a`... In my computer, at least.

Comment: And why people are downvoting the question, anyway? What's wrong with it?

Comment: 1) C and C++ are different languages with different standard libraries and different behaviour. Pick the language you actually use. 2) It is absolutely not clear what your actual problem is. Just drop the LF from the buffer. As you say, you know how to properly parse, so what?

Comment: @Olaf I edited the question.

Comment: There really isn't a need to unget the character. You can simply `fseek()` back by 1 character. `unget` is usually used on devices where characters are removed after read, such as keyboards.

Comment: @alvits That's it. My FILE* is `stdin`. `fseek()` will work too?

Comment: @matheuscscp - that's one important information you neglected to post. The more information you withheld, the less accurate comments and answers you will get. You cannot seek on pipes, sockets, keyboards. Should I really list all devices where you can't seek?

Comment: @alvits: That is nonsense. How do you seek a character stream??

Comment: @Olaf - I thought I was clear that you cannot seek some devices. A `FILE *` stream is a pointer to any devices including regular files. If the `FILE *` stream is to an opened regular file, you can seek using `fseek()`. Did that answer your question? If the `FILE *` stream is to a stream device or character device, or pipes, then you cannot seek. I am thinking of listing all such devices that cannot be seeked to avoid getting this question.

Comment: @alvits: Since you can always call ungetc, there is no point in worrying about whether the stream is seekable or not.

Comment: @alvits: It is a stream in the first place and `scanf`, `fgetc` etc. are designed to work with **any** stream - there are no "devices" in C. Worse seeking can caouse much more trouble in combination with these functions (buffering, etc.) and is very likely not faster. So what would be the advantage over `ungetc`? You have to check if the stream is seekable or not (is there even a standard way?) and implement two different ways to push back a character. Although there already is one. General advice: if there is a standard way, use it. Avoid additional complexity without good reason!

Answer (score 1):

To to safely 'unget' a character, insure

1. Only used once after getting a character.  One character of push-back is guaranteed.  Additional calls may not work.
2. Insure the value pushed back is in the range of `unsigned char`.  Pushing back `EOF` results in an unchanged stream.

Example:

```
unsigned sum = 0;
int ch;
while (isdigit(ch = fgetc(stdin))) {
  sum += ch - '0';
}
ungetc(ch, stdin);
```

Comment: ungetc'ing EOF is "safe" in the sense that it does nothing, leaving the stream with an eof indication. Of course, on an OS which doesn't correctly check the eof indicator when you call `fgetc`, you will not necessarily get another EOF indicators on the next `fgetc`, but not calling ungetc in this case doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found the answer. Since `fgetc()` won't hit EOF when you get the `'\n'` byte, it is completely safe to call `ungetc('\n')`. The descriptor (it doesn't matter the underlying device) will remain in a valid state and the subsequent call to `fgetc()` will return `'\n'`.